# Acceder al valor de un control Entry

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin

he instalado un login de SyncFusion,que trae dos controles Entry para introducir el Email y el pass del usuario. Con el pass no tengo problemas porque en el xaml lleva el atributo x:Name

```
<control:BorderlessEntry
                                    x:Name="PasswordEntry"
                                    Margin="15,0"
                                    HeightRequest="40"
                                    IsPassword="True"
                                    Placeholder="Contraseña"
                                    Style="{StaticResource BorderlessEntryStyle}"
                                    Text="{Binding Password.Value}">
                                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                                        <behaviour:EntryLineValidationBehaviour IsValid="{Binding Password.IsValid}" />
                                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                                </control:BorderlessEntry>
```

Pero para el Login tengo lo siguiente:

```
<!--  Entry to get email ID from user  -->
                    <local:SimpleEmailEntry Grid.Row="2" Padding="0,24" />
```

Esto apunta a otro archivo llamado SimpleEmailEntry.xaml con el siguiente código para el control:

```
<control:BorderlessEntry
                    x:Name="EmailEntry"
                    Margin="15,0"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    Keyboard="Email"
                    Placeholder="Email"
                    Style="{StaticResource BorderlessEntryStyle}"
                    Text="{Binding Email.Value}">
                    <Entry.Behaviors>
                        <behaviour:EntryLineValidationBehaviour IsValid="{Binding Email.IsValid}" />
                    </Entry.Behaviors>
                </control:BorderlessEntry>
```

Mi pregunta es como puedo llevar el valor de x:name=EmailEntry a la otra clase? En un principio en esta misma clase he creado un:

```
public string GetEmail()
    {
        return EmailEntry.Text;
    }
```

y desde la otra intento con:

```
SimpleEmailEntry emailEntry = new SimpleEmailEntry();
string email = emailEntry.getEmail();
```

Pero siempre me devuelve Null y ya no se en que me estoy equivocando.

Alguien puede ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno me respondo a mi mismo, el problema es que no lo estaba capturando desde el sitio correcto. En SyncFusion el email se controla desde la clase LoginPageViewModel.cs por lo que he podido sacarlo de ahí y grabarlo en la clase que me interesaba de esta forma:

```
private void LoginClicked(object obj)
    {
        if (this.AreFieldsValid())
        {
            SimpleLoginPage simpleLoginPage = new SimpleLoginPage();
            simpleLoginPage.SetEmail(Email.Value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Y ya en mi clase:

```
 public string pEmail;
    public void SetEmail(string mail)
    {
        pEmail = mail;
    }
```

Espero le sirva a alguien un saludo.